# What is difference between AndroidDriver from Selenium and java-io[Appium]?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

As there is AndroidDriver class present in both libraries while performing mobile device automation, what are the major differences in between these two classes?

1. io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
2. org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver

Comment: seems like same class in different versions of the same package? could you mention the versions of libraries you are finding these in

Comment: Libraries are different. Please verify.

Comment: That was a question, what libraries are you using to fetch each of them and their version?

Answer (score 0):

`AppiumDriver` class contains all methods shared by iOS and Android.

`IOSDriver` and `AndroidDriver` both extend `AppiumDriver` and provide more methods, and specific implementations for some methods.

Differences:

- `AppiumDriver` is an abstract class where as `AndroidDriver` is concrete class which extends `AppiumDriver` class
- `AppiumDriver` class does not implement any interface where as `AndroidDriver` class implements generic and non-generic interfaces as seen in declaration
- `AppiumDriver` is parent class and `AndroidDriver` is child class
- `AppiumDriver` contains abstract,non-abstract methods where as `AndroidDriver` being concrete class does not contains abstract methods, it just override methods of `AppiumDriver` class,`AndroidDriver` class does not add any new method to this class
- Partially we can say `AppiumDriver` is an abstract design pattern and `AndroidDriver` class is its design implementation class

Reference Links:

**http://discuss.appium.io/t/what-is-the-difference-between-appiumdriver-webelement-and-appiumdriver-mobileelement/8705/6**

**http://discuss.appium.io/t/difference-between-appiumdriver-and-androiddriver/3188**

Comment: Both are AndroidDriver classes. Please verify. Here you are explaining AppiumDriver :)